React Hooks | Mi estados no se actualizan al modificar el formulario
tengo este form para actualizar :
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { Button, Grid, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { TextareaAutosize as BaseTextareaAutosize } from "@mui/base/TextareaAutosize";
import { Button as BaseButton } from "@mui/base/Button";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { create, update } from "../redux/dogSlice";

const CrudDog = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dogs = useSelector((store) => store.dog.data);
  const [dog, setDog] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    console.log(id);
    if (id) {
      let foundDog = dogs.filter((dog) => {
        return dog.id === id;
      })[0];

      console.log(foundDog);
      setDog(foundDog);
    } else {
      setDog(null);
    }

    console.log("dog", dog);
  }, [dog, id]);

  const submit = () => {
    if (id) {
      console.log("updating..!");
      dispatch(update({ id: id, updatedDog: dog }));
    } else {
      console.log("creating..!");
      dispatch(create(dog));
    }

    navigate("/home");
  };

  const onChangeField = (e) => {
    let {name,value} = e.target;
    console.log("name = "+name + " | value = "+value);
    setDog((prevDog)=>({
      ...prevDog,
      name:value
    }))
  };

  const blue = {
    100: "#DAECFF",
    200: "#b6daff",
    400: "#3399FF",
    500: "#007FFF",
    600: "#0072E5",
    900: "#003A75",
  };

  const grey = {
    50: "#F3F6F9",
    100: "#E5EAF2",
    200: "#DAE2ED",
    300: "#C7D0DD",
    400: "#B0B8C4",
    500: "#9DA8B7",
    600: "#6B7A90",
    700: "#434D5B",
    800: "#303740",
    900: "#1C2025",
  };

  const Textarea = styled(BaseTextareaAutosize)(
    ({ theme }) => `
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: ${theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? grey[300] : grey[900]};
    background: ${theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? grey[900] : "#fff"};
    border: 1px solid ${theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? grey[700] : grey[200]};
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px ${
      theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? grey[900] : grey[50]
    };

    &:hover {
      border-color: ${blue[400]};
    }

    &:focus {
      border-color: ${blue[400]};
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px ${
        theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? blue[600] : blue[200]
      };
    }

    // firefox
    &:focus-visible {
      outline: 0;
    }
  `
  );

  const Button = styled(BaseButton)(
    ({ theme }) => `
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: ${blue[500]};
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid ${blue[500]};
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px ${
    theme.palette.mode === "dark"
      ? "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
      : "rgba(45, 45, 60, 0.2)"
  }, inset 0 1.5px 1px ${blue[400]}, inset 0 -2px 1px ${blue[600]};

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${blue[600]};
  }

  &:active {
    background-color: ${blue[700]};
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: scale(0.99);
  }

  &:focus-visible {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px ${
      theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? blue[300] : blue[200]
    };
    outline: none;
  }

  &.base--disabled {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? grey[700] : grey[200]};
    color: ${theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? grey[200] : grey[700]};
    border: 0;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
`
  );

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      columns={12}
      rowSpacing={6}
      display={"flex"}
      justifyContent={"center"}
    >
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={5} md={4} lg={5}>
        <h1 align="center">Adopt a dog</h1>
        <form action="">
          <TextField
            name="name"
            label="Dog name"
            value={dog ? dog.name : ""}
            onChange={(e)=>onChangeField(e)}
            fullWidth
          />
          <Textarea
            name="description"
            style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
            aria-label="minimum height"
            minRows={3}
            placeholder="Minimum 3 rows"
            onChange={(e) => onChangeField(e)}
          />

          <Button
            style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => {
              submit();
            }}
          >
            {dog ? "Update" : "Save"}
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default CrudDog;

Tengo puesta una funcion en el onchange del textfield y textarea (onChangeField(e)) pero no me actualiza el estado, de hecho cuando escribo algo, se ve en la casilla, por un segundo, y luego vuelve a su estado por defecto, porque me esta bloqueando el cambio ??
Mi idea es ponerle a las casillas el evento on change que comentaba y en la propia funciona centralizar la logica de seteo de variable, pero cuando intento sobreescribirla hace como un rollback a lo que habia y nunca me deja actualizarlo

Según mi interpretación el useEffect es el causante del problema. Si quieres verificar que existe un id como param, con el fin de actualizar un dog, se me ocurriría que con useState ya basta.
const { id } = useParams();

Para empezar para completar un formulario inicializaria el estado con campos vacios en caso de que no exista un id. Caso contrario completaria los campos con el registro correspondiente.
const [dog, setDog] = useState({
    id: id ? dogs.find((dog) => dog.id === id).id : "",
    name: id ? dogs.find((dog) => dog.id === id).name : "",
    description: id ? dogs.find((dog) => dog.id === id).description : ""
  });

  const { name, description } = dog

En onChange completaria un campo dependiendo del value y name del mismo.
const onChangeField = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setDog({ ...dog, [name]: value })
  };

Con respecto al uso de MUI, para establecer un formulario puedes reemplazar la etiqueta form por <Box component="form" onSubmit={sumbit}>
Con respecto al textarea puedes utilizar <TextField />
      <TextField
        name="name"
        label="Dog name"
        onChange={onChangeField}
        fullWidth
        value={name}
      />
      <TextField
        name="description"
        style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
        aria-label="minimum height"
        multiline
        rows={3}
        fullWidth
        placeholder="Minimum 3 rows"
        onChange={onChangeField}
        value={description}
      />

